# Time Series Clustering on sales data -- any ideas?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering

I have a retail store dataset, and I am interested to do some time series clustering on this data, what idea you find interesting for this purpose?

I have so far:

- What sales trends there are across time?
- What products customers will purchase at what time?
- Customer segmentation across time?

Any better ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Time series could be applied for sales in various different fields.
Here a quite extended view.
There is the ones you've mentionned:

- What sales trends there are across time.
- What products customers will purchase at what time (day/week/month/year seasonality).
- Customer segmentation across time.

And also other ones:

- Sales predictions based on stock markets correlations (raw materials,etc.).
- Sales predictions based on other events such as weather, celebration day, virus, scarcity and scarcity threats, inflation, etc. (can be found in news data source like twitter)
- Correlation study between items in space or in time (ex: sales of a product A could lead later to sales of a product B).

If available:

- Current customer profiles/population studies to make marketing predictions.
- Historical demographic data to evaluate changes and trends (purchasing power, beliefs,etc.)
- Items organisation. Some sales can be improved by puting related
  items next to each other (ex: sun glasses and ice cream).

Comment: Thank you, Given that **I** I have a retail dataset, and **II** I want to do time series clustering, and **III** I want to answer this question: which products correlated/clustered with each other across time; I have some follow-up questions if you can address please:

**1)** Which algorithms are the fastest and  suitable: Partitional (kmeans), density based (DBSCAN or HDBSCAN with hierarchical), hierarchical (agglomerative)?
**2)** Which distance measure would be suitable; correlation distance, DTW, or some other measure (I am not including Euclidean)?

Comment: You have plenty of options to cluster data interestingly. I use to suggest a dimensional reduction algorithm (like t-SNE or UMAP) because it clusterizes data relatively well. Then, you can also apply the algorithms you've mentionned or even random forest: it is usually a good option. In addition to that, XGBoost could be even better (see https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-store-demand-forecasting-and-inventory-optimization-part-1-xgboost-vs-9952d8303b48).

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111277/multi-dimensional-time-series-and-matrix-profile-method